# Drawing lines on a black JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, java-2d

Im trying to use what I have learned the last six months of java programming to recreate the classic pong game. But drawing lines isn't one of the things, even if it seems basic.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pong p = new Pong();
    p.setVisible(true);
}
/**
 * The Constructor
 */
public Pong() {
    makeFrame();
    draw(getGraphics());
}

/**
 * Making the frame for the game
 */
public void makeFrame() {
    // Frame stuff goes here
}

/**
 * Drawing the in-games lines
 */
public void draw(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.drawLine(400, 0, 400, 550);
}
```

I can't seem to get the line to draw itself. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong? 
I want the line in the middle of my screen.

**EDIT:**
Would like to thanks the guys who answered the question. Many kudos to you guys! I really appreciate the answers and the provided links! :)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Don't use getGraphics, it can return null and this isn't how painting is done. Check out [Perfoming Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swing, you are not responsible for painting, that job falls to the `RepaintManager`.  It decides what and when to paint based on a number of factors.

The recommended mechanism for performing custom painting is to crate a custom class, extending from something like `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method.  If you would like to update the component, you can request that the component be repainted by calling it's `repaint` method.

Make no mistake, this is a request only.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class QuickPaint {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new QuickPaint();
    }

    public QuickPaint() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new PaintPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class PaintPane extends JPanel {

        private int paints = 0;

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            paints++;
            super.paintComponent(g); 
            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();
            g.drawLine(width / 2, 0, width / 2, height);
            g.drawLine(0, height / 2, width, height / 2);
            g.drawLine(0, 0, width, height);
            g.drawLine(0, height, width, 0);
            String text = "Repainted " + paints + " times";
            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
            int x = (width - fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
            int y = ((height - fm.getHeight()) / 2) + fm.getAscent();
            g.drawString(text, x, y);
        }

    }

}
```

Take a close look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details...

Comment: Could it make the code look better to divide the frame into a new class, and make the movement and the score in the main class?

Comment: One concept I OO is this idea of separation of duties. That each class should do one job. So yes, in my mind, it would better to separate the logic and management of each part of your application. Swing, for example, uses the MVC model (model, control, view) when describing its API. This means that the data is modelled separately from the view and the user interactions - for example

Answer (score 2):

In Java Swing, you do not call "draw" by yourself - instead, you create a JFrame (or another top-level container, such as JApplet) and overwrite its "paint" method -- or the paint method of components that  are contained, directly or indirectly, in your root elements.

Your getGraphics() will not return an actual graphics context (those are only created for root swing components, or when building bitmap buffers for off-screen painting). So nothing will be displayed. Have a look at the [official painting tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).

The recommended approach (and the one used in the above tutorial) is to perform custom painting by overriding the paintComponent() method of a JPanel contained within your component hierarchy.

Comment: Actually, your recommend NOT to override the paint method of any top level container as they are not double buffered. Instead, use something like JPanel and override its paintComponent method

Comment: Completely agree - hence the link to the tutorial. My point was that the components paint themselves.